# How to display the video?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

I implemented loading videofiles. I used a gem paperclip-av-transcoder.

model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :video, 
                    :url => ":localhost/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                    :styles => {
                      :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv' },
                      :thumb => { :geometry => "200x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
                    }, :processors => [:transcoder] 
  validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4", "video.mov", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]
end
```

controller:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(video_params)   

  if @video.save
    flash[:success] = :video_created
    redirect_to @video
  else
    flash.now[:error] = :video_not_created
    redirect_to @video
  end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<%= @video.video_file_name %>" type="<%= @video.video_content_type %>">
</video>
```

resulting video file is loaded into the system, but not displayed.

firebug shows the wrong way:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="">
    <source src="mmm.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

actual path is:

```
/home/kalinin/rails/vd/public/system/videos/videos/17/medium/mmm.flv
```

I do not understand how to get the video on the screen.

Comment: Try `<%= video_tag @video.video.url(:medium), type: "<%= @video.video_content_type %>" %>`

Comment: in result: <video type="video/mp4" src="/videos/:localhost/system/videos/videos/17/medium/mmm.flv?1437210560"></video>

Comment: but actual path is: /home/kalinin/rails/vd/public/system/videos/videos/17/medium/mmm.flv

Comment: Ok. Try `<%= video_tag @video.video.path(:medium), type: "<%= @video.video_content_type %>" %>`

Comment: thanks, is worked/ but <%= video_tag @video.video.path(:medium), type: @video.video_content_type %>

Comment: Great. I will post my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code

```
<%= video_tag @video.video.path(:medium), type: @video.video_content_type %>
```